# Count value and delete

Tags: r

I would like to count the value in the dataset and if the count is under 4 I would like to delete the column.

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | NA | 2 |
| 2 | NA | 5 |
| 3 | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | NA | 2 |
| 3 | NA | NA |

count <> NA

In this case, if count(value<>NA) < 4 I need to delete the column, my original dataset is bigger than this so I would like to have something handy

Comment: Please clarify: `In this case if NA < 5` Do you want to count NAs? `count is under 4 / if NA < 5` Under 4 or under 5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing columns with column sums below 4

```
df[, colSums(df, na.rm=T) >= 4]
  A  C
1 1  2
2 2  5
3 3  2
4 3  2
5 3 NA
```

To delete columns with a NA count below 4 try something like this

```
df[, colSums(is.na(df)) >= 4, drop=F]
   B
1 NA
2 NA
3  1
4 NA
5 NA
```

##### Data

```
df <- structure(list(A = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L), B = c(NA, NA, 1, NA, 
NA), C = c(2L, 5L, 2L, 2L, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```